# Practical effect of using the /f option when hibernating via the Windows shutdown command?

Tags: windows, command-line, hibernate

In various examples on the internet one can see lots of calls to `shutdown /h`, but sometimes also to `shutdown /h /f` for doing the same, hibernating PC with Windows 7/8/10 - i. e. for shutting down the PC *without closing running applications*.

The [documentation for shutdown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown) states that the `/h` option which is used for hibernation may be used together with the `/f` option (and with no other one).

The documentation also gives the following description of the `/f` option:

> Forces running applications to close without warning users. Caution:
>   Using the **/f** option might result in loss of unsaved data.

Provided that hibernation "by common sense" only *pauses* applications, I cannot but ask under which circumstances the hibernation would really *close* (terminate) some application. In another words, when exactly does the `/f` option come into effect when using it together with `shutdown /h`? Or is just a bad wording in the documentation?

Answer (score 3):

The practical effect seems to be between subtle and zero, depending on your Windows version.

I used the free version of [IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml) to disassemble `shutdown.exe` and see what it does with the `/f` parameter. It's very difficult to tell from the disassembly what variable that parameter ends up setting, but I found this right before the `eax` register is used as the flags parameter to an [`InitiateShutdownW`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiateshutdownw) call:

[image]

The `SHUTDOWN_FORCE_SELF` flag has value 2 and can only be added if this variable is set, so I went ahead and named the variable `fFlag`.

But `InitiateShutdownW` doesn't seem to be able to hibernate the computer, so we'll need to look elsewhere for that logic. On a different code path, our `fFlag` variable is involved in a call to [`NtInitiatePowerAction`](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/doc/ntpoapi_8h.html#ab541ff696bc6f4c02b396adc77eb67cc):

[image]

The last `push` provides the first parameter for the call, so the `SystemAction` parameter is 3, which according to the [`POWER_ACTION` documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ne-winnt-power_action) (counting the enum entries starting from zero) does indeed specify hibernation. The other `push` of interest is the second, which determines the third parameter, `Flags`. Most of the first half of the above block is some bit twiddling to pass `0x80000000` if `fFlag` is set and zero otherwise. Unfortunately the function definition doesn't say which enum the meaning of that number comes from, but it's probably the same as the `Flags` member of the [`POWER_ACTION_POLICY` structure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-power_action_policy), in which case `0x80000000` is the value of `POWER_ACTION_CRITICAL` and "forces a critical suspension."

The question is then: what is a critical suspension? The [System Power Management Events page says](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-management-events#operational-mode-events):

> When the system carries out a *critical suspension*, the system is immediately put to sleep due to a critical condition such as a critical battery alarm. In contrast to a normal sleep transition, the system does not notify applications and drivers before carrying out a critical suspension.

Applications would be notified by the [`PBT_APMSUSPEND` event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/pbt-apmsuspend). However, I used [Spy++](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2019) to watch the messages sent and saw `PBT_APMSUSPEND` before hibernation whether or not `/f` was specified. (To double-check that `POWER_ACTION_CRITICAL` was actually being specified, I also tried calling `NtInitiatePowerAction` directly rather than using `shutdown /h /f`. I still observed no difference on Windows 10 1909.) Some power management behavior changed across Windows versions. For example, the [`PBT_APMRESUMECRITICAL` event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/pbt-apmresumecritical), which notified applications of the system's resumption from a critical suspension, was retired in Windows Vista.

My assessment is that combining `/h` with `/f` may used to have skipped sending certain notifications to "applications and drivers" but probably no longer has an effect.

Comment: +1.  This seems non-definitive (the answer starts with "seems to be" and says "probably" in the last sentence), but clearly exhibited some significant effort and expertise.  Kudos.